# Binding variables inside data template maui

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, mobile, maui

I've been trying to access a variable from my XAML code via binding. I don't know why, but I'm able to access the variable, but I don't get any value.

As you can see the IntelliSense can access the variable:

[image: ![screenshot]]

But the XAML code doesn't receive any value. When I put the variable outside the , everything works fine. Here is the code sample:

```xml
<CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,*">
            <VerticalStackLayout Grid.Column="{Binding TempColNum}">
                <Image Source="{Binding MainImage}" Aspect="AspectFit" HeightRequest="120" x:DataType="model:ImagesJson"/>
                <Label Text="{Binding Topic}" x:DataType="model:ImagesJson"/>
                <Label Text="{Binding Likes}" x:DataType="model:ImagesJson"/>
            </VerticalStackLayout>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
```

Edit:

Here is the code behind:

```cs
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using neview.Model.Profile;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
    
namespace neview.ViewModel.Profile
{
    public partial class ProfileViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        public ProfileViewModel(ImagesLoad postLoad)
        {
            tempColNum = 1;
            this.imagesLoad = postLoad;
            isRefreshing = false;
        }
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // COMMANDS
        // get images
        [RelayCommand]
        public async Task GetImagesAsync()
        {
            var localMainPost = await imagesLoad.GetImages();
            if (imagesCollection.Count() != 0)
            {
                imagesCollection.Clear();
            }
                
            foreach (var i in localMainPost)
            {
                imagesCollection.Add(i);
            }
            IsRefreshing = false;
        }
        
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // VARIABLES
        public ObservableCollection<ImagesJson> imagesCollection { get; } = new();

        ImagesLoad imagesLoad;

        [ObservableProperty]
        bool isRefreshing;

        [ObservableProperty]
        int tempColNum;
    }
}
```

Comment: how do you know its not working?  Try binding `TempColNum` to a `Label` to verify that the value is set and is getting bound correctly.  And what is the type of `TempColNum`?

Comment: TempColNum is int32 type. I tried to bind TempColNum to label text and it is showing nothing.

Comment: then you most likely have a data problem.  Have you stepped through the code in the debugger to verify that there is a value set on that property?

Comment: is that property on the `ImagesJson` model?

Comment: Nope.  I added the code into edit.

Comment: you need to use a [relative binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/relative-bindings?view=net-maui-7.0) if you want to bind to a property that is not part of current binding context

Comment: I tried, but failed (probably dont know how). Can you show me the syntax please?

Comment: You should show the surrounding XAML, not just the part with the `DataTemplate`, then it's easier to see and explain how to fix it appropriately. As @Jason already wrote, you'll need a relative binding.

Comment: please show us what you tried if you want more help.  There are many, many existing questions about relative bindings for both MAUI and XF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use a `RelativeSource`, because the binding context changes to the type of the objects that are inside the collection when using a `DataTemplate`, here that would be `ImagesJson`, while you want to bind to the `ProfileViewModel`.

Update your XAML like this:

```xml
<CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:ImagesJson">
        <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,*">
            <VerticalStackLayout Grid.Column="{Binding TempColNum, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodel:ProfileViewModel}}}">
                <Image Source="{Binding MainImage}" Aspect="AspectFit" HeightRequest="120"/>
                <Label Text="{Binding Topic}"/>
                <Label Text="{Binding Likes}"/>
            </VerticalStackLayout>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
```

<strike>Disclaimer: I'm not sure if binding the `Grid.Column` to a property will actually work, because `Grid.Column` is an attached property.</strike>